# Segwit versioning limitations

Tags: segregated-witness, script

Currently my understanding is that if new version of Segwit script is introduced, you are free to create whatever crazy rules you want there as long as they do not go against any valid consensus rules. Is that correct or are there any limitations that I'm missing?

For example, if I propose version 9 of script and convince enough nodes and miners that it is a good idea then we could soft fork to it. And the rules it would use would be exactly the same as version 0, except that the witness would be only one item instead of N items and I would say that you need to parse the actual items from this one item given that the separator is 0xdeadbeef and that the whole value is XORed by 0x11 and that the very first value is a new one that is to be discarded, but before it is discarded it has to be equal to the value used in the last version 9 script transaction +1. And with these rules I would be only limited with the size limitation of the witness. Is that correct?